# UV Mapping - How to reach always the same scale of the texture

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have an issue with the UV mapping for a longer time, but now it's time for me to fix that.
I will present the issue on an example.

I have 2 squares - one's edges are 4 meter, the other 2 meter. I expect, that when I unwrap them, that the size of the mapping is respektive to the size of the face: the 4m square would have a twice big UV map as the 2m one. But it is not like that. It doesn't matter what size the square has, the UV Map shrinks or enlarges the UV Map so that it fits into 1 "texture unit". When I then apply the texture in unity, the texture will not have the same scale. And that's not good.

What I need is, that every face is mapped so, that 1 square meter of the face is mapped to 1 "texture unit" in the UV map.

Is that possible?
I searched for it in the internet, but found just nothing.

Is there maybe somebody, who could write this functionality as a script / add-on to blender?

Thank you,
Huxi

[image]

Comment: Default built-in and not fully customizable way is to select faces on UV map and run UV > Average Islands Scale in UV editor. Another way is Texel Density Checker addon. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114408/how-do-i-unwrap-a-model-proportionally

Comment: As @Mr Zak pointed out, [Texel Density Checker](https://gumroad.com/l/CEIOR) will save you a lot of time. And it's free :).

Comment: Hi, so I bougth the Texel Density Checker and it works perfectly. I am sooooo happy. And I did not buy it for free, I spend some money on it - I am like to appreciate the effort of the people making the add-ons :)